# TSLint returns expected an assignment or function call when assigning variables

Tags: typescript, angular, tslint

I am using tslint to check my angular 2 project and am getting some errors that I don't really understand. The following code snippit gets a "expected an assignment or function call"-error, but isn't that exactly what my code is doing?

```
getUsers() {
    this._userService.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
        this.userList = data.users,
        this.number_of_pages = data.number_of_pages,
        this.number_of_users = data.number_of_users;
    });
}
```

Is this a bug or do I not understand the error correctly? I am using typescript version 1.8.10.

Edit: The error occures at the first assignment, so `this.userList = data.users`

Comment: Which is the exact line where the error occurs? Thanks!

Comment: At the first assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you don't use semi-colons but comma at the end of two lines:

```
this.userList = data.users, // <----
this.number_of_pages = data.number_of_pages, // <----
this.number_of_users = data.number_of_users;
```

You should use the following:

```
this.userList = data.users; // <----
this.number_of_pages = data.number_of_pages; // <----
this.number_of_users = data.number_of_users;
```